# Raspberry PI linker emulator mode error

Tags: unix, assembly, terminal, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Have been trying to set up assembly language codes to run on my Raspbian OS Unix Terminal (raspberry pi 2). However, after input the below commands I received an error:

```
$ nasm -f elf scanAdd.asm
$ ld -m elf_i386 -s -o scanAdd scanAdd.o
```

> "ld: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386
>   Supported emulations: armelf_linux_eabi armelfb_linux_eabi"

Anyone know whats the issue caused by?

Comment: can you show us (at least a part) of the assembler code (in scanAdd.asm), so we can see if it's x86 code you want to assemble (this won't run on a raspPI since it has a arm processor)? If you want to write a program in asm code, and run this on the PI, you have to use a different assembler (e.g. 'as' will do)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link an x86 executable (`elf_i386`) on the Raspberry Pi.

The Pi does not have an x86 processor, so the toolchain that's installed by default does not support building x86 executables. (It couldn't run them anyway.)

Comment: Is there any alternative way I can solve this issue? By default Raspberry Pi is running on ARM executable?

Comment: Simply remove the "-m elf_i386" from the linker call

Comment: After removed, I received this error again:

ld: scanAdd.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM:3)
scanAdd.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

Comment: @Roy.L I assume you're working from a tutorial? Use an x86 PC. What you're trying to do won't work on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Tommylee2k That won't help. nasm is an x86 assembler.

Comment: I am actually needed to test out an application in different platform consisting of Windows, Raspberry Pi and MAC, whereas will need to understand the conversion of the different commands and languages. Is there any way I can run the commands over in Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @Roy.L You can build custom binutils with support for x86.

Comment: @fuz I am not very familiar with Unix commands, any suggestions to start with it?

Comment: @Roy.L Open your terminal and type `man 1 intro`. This should give you an introduction. Leave the pager by typing `q`.

Comment: @fuz Had tried to read up, but still do not understand how to build custom binutils with support for x86 on the Unix platform which I am currently working on

Comment: @Roy.L while the crosscompiler for x86 will allow you to build the x86 binary on Raspberry, you will be not able to execute it. So if your goal is to "test application on different platform", then you have to build it for the target platform. If your application has x86 assembly sources, you will have to rewrite it completely for ARM (like write it second time). C/C++ is generally portable, as long as you avoid platform specific stuff, in such case you need just to recompile the C/C++ sources to get correct binary for different target platform. (or run x86 emulator on Pi => ~1% performance)

Comment: @Roy.L so if you will rewrite your sources in C/C++ in platform agnostic way, you will fix your problem on all platforms (each may require further adjustments for particular platform quirk, if the clean portable C will not work out of box). That's one of the reasons, why C was created, to avoid rewriting the SW again and again with every new platform/CPU.

Comment: @Ped7g I will take a look at it, thanks for ur info!

Comment: @Tommylee2k After I removed the "-m elf_i386", received the following output error:

ld: scanAdd.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM:3)
scanAdd.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

May I check why am I see-ing this error too?

Comment: @Roy.L You are (still!) trying to build an x86 executable on an ARM system, using ARM tools. This isn't going to work.

Comment: @duskwuff the only way left is I will need to rebuild it completely for ARM, which is to recompile the C sources (in Windows) to get the correct binary for Raspberry Pi platform? As mentioned previously by Ped7g. But how do I exactly do that?

Comment: @Roy.L Yes, you will. As you have now been told numerous times, x86 code will not run on an ARM processor.

Comment: However, I tried to setup cross build tools with the command "sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf" I get the error Unable to locate package g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf. Couldn't find any package by regex "g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf"